# How to write LDAP query to test if user is member of a group?

Tags: ldap

I want to write an LDAP query which tests whether a user (sAMAccountName) is a member of a particular group. Is it possible to do that so that I get either 0 or 1 result records?

I guess I can get all groups for the user and test each one for a match but I was wondering if I could pack it into one LDAP expression.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: See also questions like [Recursively querying LDAP group membership](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7826927/1260896)

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You should be able to create a query with this filter here:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=yourUserName)
  (memberof=CN=YourGroup,OU=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com))
```

and when you run that against your LDAP server, if you get a result, your user "yourUserName" is indeed a member of the group "CN=YourGroup,OU=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com

Try and see if this works!

If you use C# / VB.Net and System.DirectoryServices, this snippet should do the trick:

```cs
DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=yourcompany,dc=com");

DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);
srch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

srch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=yourusername)(memberOf=CN=yourgroup,OU=yourOU,DC=yourcompany,DC=com))";

SearchResultCollection res = srch.FindAll();

if(res == null || res.Count <= 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("This user is *NOT* member of that group");
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("This user is INDEED a member of that group");
}
```

Word of caution: this will only test for immediate group memberships, and it will not test for membership in what is called the "primary group" (usually "cn=Users") in your domain. It does not handle nested memberships, e.g. User A is member of Group A which is member of Group B - that fact that User A is really a member of Group B as well doesn't get reflected here.

Marc

Comment: Tried, but still not working for me. Should it be 'OU=Users' or 'OU=Groups' in the memberOf clause?

Comment: What's the DN of your group name? It depends on what you really want to check for......

Comment: You need to put in the actual real values in your case - my stuff is just demo placeholders!

Comment: This is my query:
(&(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=USERID)(memberof='CN=SPSAdmins,OU=Groups,OU=MYTOWN,OU=Germany,OU=MYCOMPANY,DC=MYTOWN,DC=MYCOMPANY,DC=com'))
The DN really is that long. I agree that it *ought* to work. Thanks for helping!

Comment: On a whim I removed the single quotes after memberof and I now get a result! Thanks

Comment: Is the memberof keyword case sensitive? On active-directory I only got memberOf (note captial O) to work.

Comment: Good answer. but it should be pointed out that it will only work in LDAP servers that maintain a 'memberOf' attribute. The more general technique is to fetch the *group* object and examine its uniqueMember, roleOccupant, etc. attributes for the DN of the user, depending on what schema the group object uses.

Comment: @Gunslinger LDAP attribute names and values aren't case-sensitive, and neither are DNs, but AD has its own rules ...

Comment: This works perfectly on AIX 7.1: `ldapsearch -h dc1.example.com -D user@example.com -w \? -b DC=example,DC=com -v "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=AIX-users,OU=AIX,DC=example,DC=com))"`

Comment: I know this is old, but I get tired of people perpetuating FUD about AD LDAP. Per the RFCs for LDAP, the DN is not case-sensitive. However, unlike other LDAP implementations, you can't perform a case-sensitive *query* (btw, not a mandatory feature in LDAP). The only exception is when performing searches for boolean values: i.e. TRUE/FALSE must be uppercase.

Answer (score 44):

If you are using OpenLDAP (i.e. slapd) which is common on Linux servers, then you must enable the memberof overlay to be able to match against a filter using the (memberOf=XXX) attribute.

Also, once you enable the overlay, it does not update the memberOf attributes for existing groups (you will need to delete out the existing groups and add them back in again). If you enabled the overlay to start with, when the database was empty then you should be OK.

Comment: A link to a page that explains how to enable memberof overlay would be useful i guess.

Comment: Tutorial that worked for me: http://www.schenkels.nl/2013/03/how-to-setup-openldap-with-memberof-overlay-ubuntu-12-04/

@Telford Tendrys, dude you saved my life with this notice about pre-existing groups. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks, wasted so much time trying to make this work in openldap, didn't know this memberOf didn't come out of the box.

Answer (score 27):

I would add one more thing to Marc's answer: The memberOf attribute can't contain wildcards, so you can't say something like "memberof=CN=SPS*", and expect it to find all groups that start with "SPS".

Comment: Thank you for that information. I've been trying to do what you say can not be done. How can I go about doing that with PHP? Is it possible to have the same result in another way? to find all groups start with SPS and then whatever...

I can always grab everything and loop my array then preg match to the CN I want but I prefer just searching for it straight up if possible.

Answer (score 20):

You must set your query base to the DN of the user in question, then set your filter to the DN of the group you're wondering if they're a member of.  To see if jdoe is a member of the office group then your query will look something like this:

```
ldapsearch -x -D "ldap_user" -w "user_passwd" -b "cn=jdoe,dc=example,dc=local" -h ldap_host '(memberof=cn=officegroup,dc=example,dc=local)'
```

If you want to see ALL the groups he's a member of, just request only the 'memberof' attribute in your search, like this:

```
ldapsearch -x -D "ldap_user" -w "user_passwd" -b "cn=jdoe,dc=example,dc=local" -h ldap_host **memberof**
```