# ActiveDirectory DirectorySearcher: Check if user is member of a group

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to know if a given user is member of a group or not. Now, I don't know much about ActiveDirecory or Exchange servers, but in Outlook I can see that a user can be "memberOf" a group (and i can query those groups with `DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberof");`), but there are also other groups that users are not actively *members of*, but that *contain* users. If you mail to those groups (or aliases) you reach all the users contained in it.

Basically, given a username (like `DOMAIN\JDoe`), how to check if it is contained in the group `FUNNY_USERS` in C#?

Answer (score 12):

Use the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace added in .Net 3.5 if it's available.  Here's an example for group checking:

```
using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
using(var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "DOMAIN\JDoe"))
using(var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "FUNNY_USERS"))
{
    return user.IsMemberOf(group);
 }
```

Comment: You need to dispose of pc, user and group.

Comment: It does not show parent of parents (Group A have nested Group B, user X member of B - userX.IsMemberOf(GroupA) = false). Is there any way to make it work without coding recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Get all members in a group:

http://snipplr.com/view/4646/get-members-of-an-active-directory-distribution-group/

Once you have the list just loop through the usernames once.

Or:

[Function to return all the groups the user is a member of](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2133.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The users you see in Outlook is probably distribution groups. There are distribution groups and security groups in Active Directory. It seems like you want to check for either/or.

See my post at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188954/see-if-user-is-part-of-active-directory-group-in-c-sharp-asp-net/14613812#14613812) for an example in C# using only ldap calls