# Determine if a user belongs to a particular AD Group using .Net

Tags: .net, active-directory

What is the best way to determine if a user belongs to particular AD user group using C# without have to enumerate through all the user's groups. Can this be done using a single LDAP query or search?

Comment: possible duplicate of [See if user is part of Active Directory group in C# + Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188954/see-if-user-is-part-of-active-directory-group-in-c-asp-net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write LDAP query to test if user is member of a group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032351/how-to-write-ldap-query-to-test-if-user-is-member-of-a-group)

Answer (score 34):

If you are checking the current user and you know the name of the group you want, you shouldn't need to enumerate through all the groups. Here's example code in VB.NET:

```
Public Function IsInGroup(ByVal GroupName As String) As Boolean
    Dim MyIdentity As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    Dim MyPrincipal As System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal = New System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(MyIdentity)
    Return MyPrincipal.IsInRole(GroupName)
End Function
```

Similarly in C#:

```
private static bool IsInGroup(string GroupName)
{
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity MyIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal MyPrincipal = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(MyIdentity);
    return MyPrincipal.IsInRole(GroupName);
}
```

More examples can be found in the [WindowsIdentity documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx), if you need to tweak it to check a different user's membership or whatever.

Comment: This was tremendously helpful to me.  If you need to check a different user's membership just do this: var userPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(new WindowsIdentity(username));

Comment: This works but you will not get information for all groups, just some of them.
In order to get a full list of groups that user is member of, check this answer:
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252108/query-from-ldap-for-user-groups)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, @Roboblob!

Comment: In my environment with 1300+ groups, IsInRole() is orders of magnitude faster than GetAuthorizationGroups() -- which takes several seconds to complete. I'm still using GetAuthorizationGroups() as a backup to test for indirect group membership when IsInRole() is negative. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you do have to enumerate groups.

Have a look at these two answers for a variety of techniques:

[See if user is part of Active Directory group in C# + Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188954/see-if-user-is-part-of-active-directory-group-in-c-asp-net)

[How to write LDAP query to test if user is member of a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032351/how-to-write-ldap-query-to-test-if-user-is-member-of-a-group)