# Authenticating against Active Directory Group

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a website using HTML/CSS to display a SQL reports index.  This has worked fine up till now because users needed access to a security group and something inside SQL to view the report and the data fields.  We are now getting to the stage where there are too many reports and some have sensitive names so we need to limit access based on Active Directory security groups.  Thing is that I have no clue at all how to manage access via AD Groups.  I have managed to get basic AD authentication working for another project that I deployed for the company, but that didn't require access beyond Domain Users.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction to authenticate via AD, check a user for groups and then display info based on their access.  The last bit should be really easy, the hardest part will be checking group info and then filling a variable that I can then use to create a loop that will display all the reports the user has access to.

Comment: I hope you search for similar things in stackoverflow. See here for solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188954/see-if-user-is-part-of-active-directory-group-in-c-sharp-asp-net and modify as per your need.

Comment: I have seen the linked Question before but I am still enough of a noob that I couldn't get it to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a partial answer.  The below link is a guide on how to pull all AD groups a user belongs to and then checking to see if they are a member of a certain group.  This is largely what I was looking for and if I can meld it into what I want, I think I can use this to do what I need.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/test-for-user-group-membership-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively Microsoft windows server can also run LDAP which has an unbelievable number of compatible libraries to code with.

tutorial linked, its just another server role/feature you can install (like ad itself)

http://osqa.sjsoft.com/questions/248/how-do-i-install-minimal-active-directoryldap-services-on-windows-server-2008

also here is a Q.A.D SO answer to querying user-groups are you using windows framework like asp? whats your server technology?
[Query From LDAP for User Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252108/query-from-ldap-for-user-groups)