# IIS7: classic ASP application write access to .mdb file using windows authentication

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I have a classic ASP application I want to run on my website (IIS7). This site contains an .mdb database file. I have enabled windows authentication and disable anonymous under authentication. I want members of a certain domain group (TESTGROUP) to have access to write to the database through the website, but I don't want them to have direct access to the files through windows. I cannot seem to find the correct permissions for the .mdb file to make this possible.

Comment: This app is already written and is being moved from an IIS6 server to an IIS7 server. The IIS6 version require the user to login. I was hoping to skip that step by using Windows Authentication, but wanted to keep the Access database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, that's not directly possible with Ms Access. Why not using Sql Server Express, it's free, much more stable and you have full control of your access rights.

If you have to use MsAccess, why not add a Webservice before it, and use active directory for access control.

This is a good start:
[See if user is part of Active Directory group in C# + Asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188954/see-if-user-is-part-of-active-directory-group-in-c-asp-net)

Comment: when i use windows authentication, does that mean that any access to files by that application are viewed as that user vs NETWORK SERVICES, IUSR, or any other account?

Comment: well what could work is to give them no access to the filesystem, you could block the smb ports on the firewall of the specific server. Or simply not share the mdb folder.