# How to condense this PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I am creating a code to open a website if a user is in a certain AD group and when connected to a certain network. This is what I have got so far:

```
$user = $env:username
$group1 = "examplegroup1"
$group2 = "examplegroup2"

if (Test-Connection "examplenetwork" -Quiet)
{      
$members1 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1 | Select -ExpandProperty 
SamAccountName

$members2 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2 | Select -ExpandProperty 
SamAccountName

If ($members1 -contains $user -or $members2 -contains $user) {Start-Process 
"examplewebsite"}
}
```

It works as it should, opening the website if the user is in the correct group and on the network, however I was just wondering if there was a way to condense the code?

It seems a waste to have to create 2 '`$groups`' and then repeat the `Get-ADGroupMember` aswell. I have played around with 'ForEach' but haven't managed to get it to work.

Any ideas on how to condense this? Preferably using the ForEach cmdlet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because working code is off topic, and the SE site for reviewing / suggesting changes to working code is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are also assuming that the end user's computer will have AD module installed in it. If you are designing it as a logon script, you are going to run into that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although my other answer is 'don't do that', if you do want your code, condensed:

```
$groups = 'group1', 'group2'

if ((Test-Connection -ComputerName "examplenetwork" -Quiet) -and 
    ($env:USERNAME -in ($groups | Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive).SamAccountName))
{
    Start-Process "www.example.com"
}
```

You really don't need either foreach.

Comment: Thanks, TessellatingHeckler. This is what I was looking for. I'm very new to Powershell (as you can probably tell) and the pipeline is one thing I need to increase my knowledge on! As for the AD problem.... I will have to address that tomorrow! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
If (("examplegroup1", "examplegroup2" | % {Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_} | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName) -Contains $env:username) {Start-Process "examplewebsite"}
```

Comment: That could start the process two times if the user is contained in both groups.

Comment: @ TToni: No, the `-unique` argument should prevent that

Comment: In fact, the `-unique` is not even required (I have removed it from the answer) as `If (<group member collection> -contains $env:username) {<ScripBlock>}` will never run the given `<scriptblock>` more then once even if the `<group member collection>` contains duplicate members.

Comment: Unnecessary `% {}` - you can pipe group names into Get-ADGroupMember directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it backward:

```
$user = $env:username
$groups = "examplegroup1", "examplegroup1"

$CheckMembership = Get-ADUser -Identity $user -Property MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf | Where-Object { $_ -in $groups }

if ($CheckMembership) {
   Start-Process "http://www.example.com"
}
```

You'd want to make sure your list of groups was a list of distinguished names, but other than that this reduces the number of AD queries to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Anything which relies on `Get-AD___` needs the RSAT tools to get the ActiveDirectory module, that's an unlikely assumption for end user workstations as @Rohin Sidharth comments.

@James C.'s currently accepted answer will not handle recursive group membership (would need the `-Recursive` parameter), but also involves listing all the members of both groups - imagine if that was a billion members for each group - and it has the poor habit of array addition.

@Bacon Bits answer gets the user's group membership which is better for 'getting less data' but still won't handle recursive group membership and still relies on the ActiveDirectory module.

To avoid RSAT, something like ADSI could be used - which is wrapped by System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement. Discussed [here](https://richardspowershellblog.wordpress.com/2008/05/25/system-directoryservices-accountmanagement/) by Richard Siddaway.

That has a nice method to list the group members for a user, which appears to be broken - pinching from Terry Tsay's C# answer on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613812/478656), I port his code to this but I've focused on the current user and included distribution groups by default:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Function IsUserInGroup([string] $groupName)
{
    # Remove DOMAIN\ from the start of the groupName.
    $groupName = $groupName -replace '^.*\\'


    # Get an AD context for the current user's domain
    $context = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList 'Domain', $ENV:USERDOMAIN


    # Find the current user account in AD, and refresh the security and distribution groups 
    $user = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, 'SAMAccountName', $env:USERNAME)
    $userEntry = [System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry] $user.GetUnderlyingObject()
    $userEntry.RefreshCache(@('tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal'))


    # Get all the security and distribution groups the user belongs to, including nested memberships
    $usersGroupSIDs = foreach ($sid in $userEntry.Properties.tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal.Value)
    {
        New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier -ArgumentList $sid, 0   
    }


    # Get the AD details for the group to test, and test membership
    $group = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, 'SamAccountName', $groupName)

    $usersGroupSIDs.Contains($group.Sid)
}
```

e.g.

```
PS C:\> IsUserInGroup 'parent-nested-group-here'
True
```

Which isn't condensed or simpler, but it should handle more conditions with less AD connecting overhead especially as member count of groups increases, and less need for extra modules, just using the .Net framework.

Then you could modify that to do

```
$group2 = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($context, 'SamAccountName', $group2Name)

$usersGroupSIDs.Contains($group.Sid) -or $usersGroupSIDs.Contains($group2.Sid)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add a `foreach` loop, but in would complicate what is already a very small and simple script.

The most I'd do is add the memberships from both groups together...

```
$user = $env:username
$group1 = "examplegroup1"
$group2 = "examplegroup2"

if (Test-Connection "examplenetwork" -Quiet)
{      
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group1 | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

    $members += Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group2 | Select -ExpandPropertySamAccountName

    If ($members -contains $user) {Start-Process "http://www.example.com"}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the "*It seems a waste to have to repeat the Get-ADGroupMember*" part, but it does change it so that it now breaks if Group1 has only one member.