# GroupPrincipal.GetMembers fails when group (or child group if recursive) contains ForeignSecurityPrincipal

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

**This is not so much a question as information for anyone experiencing the same problem.**

The following error occurs:

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: An error (87) occurred while enumerating the groups. The group's SID could not be resolved. 
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SidList.TranslateSids(String target, IntPtr&#91;&#93; pSids) 
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SidList.ctor(List`1 sidListByteFormat, String target, NetCred credentials) 
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADDNLinkedAttrSet.TranslateForeignMembers()
```

When the following code is run and a group or child group contains a ForeignSecurityPrincipal:

```
private static void GetUsersFromGroup()
{
    var groupDistinguishedName = "CN=IIS_IUSRS,CN=Builtin,DC=Domain,DC=com";
    //NB: Exception thrown during iteration of members rather than call to GetMembers.    
    using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain", "Username", "Password"))
    {
        using (GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, groupDistinguishedName))
        {                    
            using (var searchResults = groupPrincipal.GetMembers(true))//Occurs when false also.
            {
                foreach (UserPrincipal item in searchResults.OfType())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found user: {0}", item.SamAccountName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***I raised a support call with Microsoft and they have confirmed it as an issue.  A bug has been raised internally but it has not been confirmed whether this will be fixed.***

Microsoft suggested the following workaround code but it performs poorly on groups with a large number of users because of the repeated calls to UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity.

```
class Program
{
    //"CN=IIS_IUSRS,CN=Builtin,DC=dev-sp-sandbox,DC=local"; //TODO MODIFY THIS LINE ACCORDING TO YOUR DC CONFIGURATION

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: ListGroupMembers \"group's DistinguishedName\"");
            Console.WriteLine("Example: ListGroupMembers \"CN=IIS_IUSRS,CN=Builtin,DC=MyDomain,DC=local\"");
            return;
        }

        string groupDistinguishedName = args[0];

        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "dev-sp-dc", "Administrator", "Corp123!");
        List<UserPrincipal> users = new List<UserPrincipal>();
        listGroupMembers(groupDistinguishedName, ctx, users);

        foreach (UserPrincipal u in users)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(u.DistinguishedName);
        }
    }

    //Recursively list the group's members which are not Foreign Security Principals
    private static void listGroupMembers(string groupDistinguishedName, PrincipalContext ctx, List<UserPrincipal> users)
    {
        DirectoryEntry group = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupDistinguishedName);
        foreach (string dn in group.Properties["member"])
        {

            DirectoryEntry gpMemberEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + dn);
            System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection userProps = gpMemberEntry.Properties;

            object[] objCls = (userProps["objectClass"].Value) as object[];

            if (objCls.Contains("group"))
                listGroupMembers(userProps["distinguishedName"].Value as string, ctx, users);

            if (!objCls.Contains("foreignSecurityPrincipal"))
            {                    
                UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, dn);
                if(u!=null)  // u==null for any other types except users
                    users.Add(u);
            }
        }                 
    }
}
```

The above code could be modified to find foreign security principals causing problems in groups.

**Microsoft provided the following information about the foreign security principals:**

This is a class of objects in AD which represents a security principal from an external source (so another forest/domain or one of the “special” accounts below). 
The class is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221858(v=PROT.10).aspx
And the container is documented here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc200915(v=PROT.10).aspx 
A FSP is not a real object in AD, but rather a placeholder (pointer) to an object which lives in a different, trusted domain/forest. It can also be one of the “special identities” which are a bunch of well-known accounts who are also classed as FSP’s because their SID’s are different to the domain SID. 
For example the anonymous, Authenticated User, batch and several other accounts as documented here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779144(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: Did you ever have the chance to try out my answer?  or did you take an alternate route?

Comment: Do you know if this bug has ever been fixed in a newer .net framework version?

Answer (score 4):

Sure this is an old thread, but might help someone.  I used the below code block the solve the problem. the Principal class exposes a property called StructuralObjectClass which tells you what is the AD Class of that principal. I used this to decide whether the object is a user. The GetMembers(true) recursively searches all nested-members in the groupPrincipal in question.

Hope this helps someone.

```
    List<UserPrincipal> members = new List<UserPrincipal>();
    foreach (var principal in groupPrincipal.GetMembers(true))
    {
        var type = principal.StructuralObjectClass;
        if (type.Contains("user"))
            members.Add((UserPrincipal)principal);
    }
```

Thanks,
R

Comment: `foreach` will fail if `groupPrincipal.GetMembers()` count is 0.

Answer (score 2):

The accountmanagement library has many saddening defects, this is just another of the many...

One thing you can do to make things slightly faster would be to adjust your LDAP query so that it checks both group membership and object type at the same time as part of the query instead of in the loop.  Honestly I doubt it will make much difference though.

Most of the inspiration for the query came from  [How to write LDAP query to test if user is member of a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032351/how-to-write-ldap-query-to-test-if-user-is-member-of-a-group).

Query:  `(&(!objectClass=foreignSecurityPrincipal)(memberof=CN=YourGroup,OU=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com))`

Note: This is an untested query...

IF there was a way to run an LDAP query in AccountManagement (another gripe of mine) then this would be the end of your troubles as you could run the query and let AccountManagement take it from there, but this option does not exist...

Based on personal experience I don't see any other options if you stick with AccountManagement.  What you could do is dump AccountManagement and use just DirectoryServices.  Under the hood all AccountManagement does is wrap DirectoryEntry objects anyways, you could write a few helper classes to do similar things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Peter.  Not tried your suggestions yet.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use this code to get the members:

```
var pth = "LDAP://ex.invalid/CN=grpName,OU=Groups,OU=whatever,DC=ex,DC=invalid";
var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(pth);
var members = dirEntry.Invoke("Members"); //COM object
foreach (var member in (IEnumerable)members) {
    var userEntry = new DirectoryEntry(member); //member is COM object
    var sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[]) userEntry.InvokeGet("objectSid"), 0);
    var typ = typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount);
    var account = (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typ);
    Console.WriteLine(account.Value);
}
```

Comment: You unsung hero. This is the only solution in years of trying that worked!