# How to add user to a group in Active Directory using PrincipalContext

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to create a user and add a certain user to an Active Directory group using C#.

The user creation is working properly, but adding user to groups is throwing an exception

> Information about the domain could not be retrieved (1355)

Here is my code:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ip, user, password))
{
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, groupname);                              

    UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, username);                               

    group.Members.Add(up);
    group.Save();   // here the exception is thrown
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782932/c-sharp-active-directory-add-user-to-group-in-another-domain

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Thanks for reply but this also throwing error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065327/information-about-the-domain-could-not-be-retrieved-1355

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy your help is appreciable, but that I already that one.