# Check if user is a member of a group (ldap)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, ldap, compact-framework

I want to check if a user is a member of a group in c#. The application is running on windows mobile 6.1 and I have to use the ldap functions with `[DllImport]`.

Anybody has a sample for this?
Connection to the ldap server and check user/password works.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use what is already in the framework.

Take a look at this: [WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs485fwh(VS.85).aspx)

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
principal.IsInRole("role name");
```

OR

If you use C# / VB.Net and System.DirectoryServices, this snippet should do the trick:

```
DirectoryEntry rootEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=yourcompany,dc=com");

DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(rootEntry);
srch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

srch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=yourusername)(memberof=CN=yourgroup,OU=yourOU,DC=yourcompany,DC=com))";

SearchResultCollection res = srch.FindAll();

if(res == null || res.Count <= 0)
    Console.WriteLine("This user is NOT a member of this group");
else
    Console.WriteLine("This user is INDEED a member of this group");
```

Word of caution: this will only test for immediate group memberships, and it will not test for membership in what is called the "primary group" (usually "cn=Users") in your domain. It does not handle nested memberships, e.g. User A is member of Group A which is member of Group B - that fact that User A is really a member of Group B as well doesn't get reflected here.

Reference: [How to write LDAP query to test if user is member of a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032351/how-to-write-ldap-query-to-test-if-user-is-member-of-a-group)

Comment: This question is specifically about the Compact Framework (I've clarified in the tags), which doesn't have any support for `WindowsPrincipal` or `DirectoryEntry`.